# Perl threads documentation and Its path

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using `threads` module in my program.

but when I run the `test.pl` script I got this error:

```
Can't locate threads.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perl5.00503/lib/5.00503/sun4-solaris /opt/perl5.00503/lib/5.00503 /opt/perl5.00503/lib/site_perl/5.005/sun4-solaris /opt/perl5.00503/lib/site_perl/5.005 .) at ./test.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 10.
```

where I can find `threads.pm` and include it in `@INC` variable?

and although threads module is available from perl 5.8 and later, but is there any other thread module that available from perl 5.00503?

Comment: You mean CPAN's threads.pm? [link](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/threads-1.89/lib/threads.pm) and you already installed it?

Comment: @HirofumiTamori I typed `perldoc threads` and I found it, which means that it is installed on my machine.

Comment: Nevertheless, you could try (re-)?installing it in cpan `install /threads-1.89/` and tell us what happens.

Comment: tried 

    ls /opt/*/threads.pm 

?

Answer (score 1):

threading support is not just something you can add-on. It has to be built into the interpreter from the ground up. The threads module provides an interface to built-in threading support added in 5.8

You could try using [forks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks). It provides the same interface as [threads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads), but uses processes instead of threads.

You didn't say why you needed threads. It might also be possible that the co-operative multitasking provided by [Coro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Coro) will do the trick?

Comment: My script is to automate installation for some software written in a specific file.
My script first read the software's names from the file then create a thread to make the installation.
Do you think that `fork` is more efficient in my case of `threads`?

Comment: In your case, I'd say forks is more efficient than something that doesn't exist.